# Does restarting CF server log everyone out?

Tags: coldfusion

If CF server is restarted, are all the existing Session and Client variables lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client variables generally live in a database or registry, and therefore they do persist after server restarts (see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html)).

Session variables live in RAM and therefore do not persist through a server restart (see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html)).